# Image in user control does not display

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have a custom control that includes an image. It shows up in the VS designer pane but when included in a form the image does not show up. What am I missing?

```
<Image Name="TheImage" x:FieldModifier="public"
    Grid.Column="0"
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  
        Source="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Resources/Sample.jpg" 
        Margin="0,0,0,0" />
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Source="/AssemblyName;component/Resources/Sample.jpg"
```

Comment: Also make sure the image file's Build Action is set to `Resource`.

Comment: I did both; no change

Comment: I have no idea what changed, but this started working. So I must have done something but I don't know what ...